# DOMPDF PHP library does not add accessibility tags

Tags: php, pdf-generation, dompdf

I need to generate a fully accessible PDF programmatically in PHP.

I've tried to use DOMPDF with Adobe Auto-tagging REST API. However, in that way, images are missing "alt" text and PDF is not compliant with WCAG. Is there any good way to generate a fully accessible PDF programmatically in PHP?

Comment: Please don't do create duplicates intentionally. You [asked this question here already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193243/dompdf-php-library-doesnt-add-accessibility-tags). We see it.

Comment: That being said. I understand you're looking for a solution, but take note of the reason your previous question was closed in the first place. That means: Change your question to [something that is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77193243/dompdf-php-library-doesnt-add-accessibility-tags).

Answer (score 0):

You can download TCPDF from the official website (https://tcpdf.org/) and follow the installation instructions. Alternatively, you can use Composer to install TCPDF:
composer require tecnickcom/tcpdf
<?php
require_once('path_to_tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', 
false);

$pdf->SetCreator('Your Name');
$pdf->SetAuthor('Your Name');
$pdf->SetTitle('Accessible PDF Example');
$pdf->SetSubject('An accessible PDF document');
$pdf->SetKeywords('PDF, accessibility, WCAG');

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$pdf->AddPage();

// Add your content with proper HTML markup
$html = '<h1>My Accessible PDF</h1>';
$html .= '<p>This is a paragraph of text.</p>';
$html .= '<img src="path_to_image.jpg" alt="Alternative Text for Image" />';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

// Output the PDF
$pdf->Output('accessible_pdf.pdf', 'I');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, TCPDF doesn't add accessibility tags as well.